# Syntax error in MySQL near SELECT

Tags: mysql

My SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS
SELECT * FROM usmanpostaddress2
UNION SELECT FROM usman_post_address0 
UNION SELECT FROM usman_post_address1 
UNION SELECT FROM usman_post_address3
UNION SELECT FROM usman_post_address4
```

Gives me this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from usmanpostaddress2 UNION select from usman_post_address0 UNION select ' at line 2

Comment: Please fix your questions title. The error message does not mark the `UNION` statement as the issue location, but the `FROM`.

Comment: The reason probably is that `SELECT FROM` is invalid SQL. "SELECT _what_ FROM..."?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the column names to select from table. Your `SELECT` statement should be

```
create table MERGED 
as 
select * from usmanpostaddress2 
UNION 
select * from usman_post_address0 
UNION 
select * from usman_post_address1 
UNION 
select * from usman_post_address3 
UNION 
select * from usman_post_address4
```